# ILogger Dependency Injection with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, ilogger

So I'm trying to setup ILogger with Dependency Injection and I'm having some trouble.

In my `startup.cs` file I have something that looks like this:

```
        builder.Services.AddLogging();
```

I then try to feed that logger to my own class (which acts like a wrapper around the ILogger library)

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoggingWrapper>(s =>
    {
        return new LoggingWrapper(
            s.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());
    });
```

So in my Azure function, `LoggingWrapper` gets injected inside, but it doesn't log anything. The normal ILogger that comes with each function still works, but I'm wondering as to why my wrapper isn't logging anything.

Logging Wrapper is a class that takes the ILogger methods and uses it to create it's own logging methods. For example `loggingWrapper.logInformation("string")` is a method that would wrap around `ILogger.

I inject this into my other classes like this: `s.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()`

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Show where the logger is injected and used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the same problem - you need to setup/allow logging from other sources:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "YourNamespace": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

More information here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging

Comment: Information: This is the `host.json` file

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to inject an ILogger?

```
//NOT...                     <LoggingWrapper>
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(s =>
{
    return new LoggingWrapper(
        s.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());
});
```

Comment: So LoggerWrapper is a class that hides all the ILogger methods and uses them to create it's own log methods. When I inject it into a class, I do so like `s.GetService<IAccountUpdaterLogger>()`, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @idude s.GetService() is "service location", not "dependency injection". They're similar patterns, but the only thing that will be injected by a given framework is whatever is accepted in the constructor (ILogger in this case). Try having LoggingWrapper implement ILogger, then follow a "decorator" pattern, accepting an internal ILogger when you instantiate it.