# How to use Ilogger in different methods?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to use Ilogger to log different things in different methods for my Azure Function. As a standard the Ilogger is used in the methods parameters. But this wont work for me as I need to be able to call my methods without parameters.

Example:

```
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 10 * * *")] Ilogger logger)
        {
            await Method2()
        }

        public static async Task<String> Method2()
        {
          Method3()
          //Here I need to also log using Ilogger.
        }

        public static async Task<String> Method3()
        {
          //Here I need to also log using Ilogger.
        }
```

The solution would be in my head to also have the Ilogger logger used as a parameter for the Method2. But this will lead to a problem, as I then need to have it in my Run method.

So I do not know how I am able to log in different methods.

I have in total 5 methods that it would be needed to log in.

I have done some research on the Ilogger, but I could not find anything relating to my direct problem.

I thought making a constructor with the Ilogger in like so:

```
   public class Function1
    {

        private static ILogger<Function1> logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            Function1.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 10 * * *")])
        {
            await Method2()
            logger.Loginformation("Log stuff");
        }

       public static async Task<String> Method2()
       {
         //Here I need to also log using Ilogger.
         logger.Loginformation("Log stuff");
       }
   ...
   }
```

I have read this could work. I have done some debugging with this and changed a bit, but without luck.

If anyone have some ideas or solution on how to solve this, please do let me know :)

**EDIT:**

I have made it so it is no longer static, and changed it to the following:

```
    public class Function1
    {

        private ILogger<Function1> logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 10 * * *")])
        {
            await Method2()
            this.logger.Loginformation("Log stuff");
        }

       public async Task<String> Method2()
       {
         this.logger.Loginformation("Log stuff");
       }
   ...
   }
```

I have no exceptions, I tried to debug this, but unfortunately without luck to find the reason for the problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you use a static property for the logger ?

Comment: Yes. In order to use it in the constructor it needs to be static.

Comment: @AlexanderThomsen no, it does not. For example make it non-static and `this.logger = logger;`. Or (maybe better) use different names for ctor parameters and properties/fields.

Comment: @GuruStron You are right, I can make it like you suggested, but I will still not be able to log.

Comment: This is the typical kind of corner you paint yourself into when using `static`. Stop using `static`. Go with the `class` approach (which you will hopefully rename to something that makes sense as opposed to a class called `Function1`) and drop `static` everywhere. Also drop it from `private static ILogger<Function1> logger;` Forget `static` exists.

Comment: As @GuruStron said, it does not need to be static. See my answer below. Using a non-static property, you are able to access your logger without having to add it has method parameter

Comment: And is the looger configurated correctly? Will it write in a file or in the console?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía It should be able to log it in the console. And can you explain what you mean with configurating the logger. As I have not configurated anything.

Comment: Well, you could use different loggers, for example Serilog is very common. And this needs to configure level of log, for example debug, warning, errors... Which logger are you using?

Comment: Please provide full [mre], desired and actual output.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a static property for the logger :

```
 public class Function1
    {

        private readonly ILogger<Function1> logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 10 * * *")])
        {
            await Method2()
            this.logger.Loginformation("Log stuff");
        }

       public async Task<String> Method2()
       {
         //Here I need to also log using Ilogger.
         this.logger.Loginformation("Log stuff");
       }
   ...
   }
```

Using a non-static property, you will be able to access your logger from everywhere in your class. So no need to add it as a method parameter.

Making your method non-static will allow you to use `this` to access your instance related properties.

Comment: Thank you for the notice for the problem using Static. But the problem still continues. :)

Comment: Describe your problem, do you have any exception thrown, is it your IDE that highlights a line of code ? Something else ?

Comment: I have no execptions thrown, no, and I have tried to debug it, but without luck to track the reason for it not logging.

Comment: I feel like this is more a configuration issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407486/10458514

Comment: I have been making some more reading, and found a video that shows what I want to do. I also followed this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN9Rmf0PUG4,  in hope that it would solve my issue. But it did not, I have still not logged anything yet. I have made my configurations to be what I believe is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not use a static property for the logger!

- You can pass the logger instance as parameter to the static methods.
- Or you make the static methods non-static and access the logger via a non static property.