# How to write logs to Azure application Insights from Asp.Net Core application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am trying to write logs to the Azure application but It's not writing the all logs. There are no errors or exceptions. Please help. I have referred to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#enable-application-insights-server-side-telemetry-no-visual-studio) document.

I have made the below changes.

Just created the Web API project from VS 2022 targeting to .Net 6.

Added the below line to the default templated code.

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

[image]

Added the below to appsettings.json.

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "MyConnectionString"
  }
```

Added these logs.

```
_logger.LogInformation("VivekLogInformation");
_logger.LogTrace("VivekLogTrace");
_logger.LogCritical("VivekLogCritical");
_logger.LogDebug("VivekLogDebug");
_logger.LogWarning("VivekLogWarningn");
```

[image]

Run the application and call the action method.

I have tried to run the below query to check the logs.

```
traces
| where message contains "Vivek"
```

**Note**: This is my first time trying to write to application insights.

I am able to see logs by adding these lines. But it only writes **VivekLogWarningn** and **VivekLogCritical** in logs. I have tried changing the Default LogLevel to Debug as well. But it's not writing all logs.

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddApplicationInsights();
});
```

I have tried this now.

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
  }
}
```

Comment: What’s the log level configuration in your app settings file?

Comment: @GauravMantri added to the question at the end, please check now

Comment: Annoyingly, Application Insights has its own log subsection inside the `Logging` section - it ignores the default logging section
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637732/314291
Take especial note of the nesting: 
`Logging->ApplicationInsights->LogLevel -> ...`

Comment: @StuartLC It looks like you are right. I am able to see the logs now.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems too when I tried to use Application Insights. Check out this StackOverFlow to see if you can find anything usefull - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75984145/how-to-use-ilogger-in-different-methods)

**Note**

Note that this is using Ilogger to log with Application Insights